# Проверка всех точек вокруг заданной на совпадение с оной с различным шагом

Tags: java, алгоритм, поиск

Есть массив точек созданных на основе BufferedImage методом:

```
  int[] imgRGB = img.getRGB(0, 0, width, hight, null, 0, width);
```

И нужно реализовать возможность сравнения точки со всеми окружающими ее на определенный шаг. То есть если точка находится на нулевой позиции(а может на любой вообще) в массиве сделанном на основе изображения 4х4(а может и в много большем), а шаг 1, то точку с индексом 0 надо будет сравнить с точками имеющими индексы: 4(нижний), 5(диагональ лево-низ), 1(левый).
Если же увеличить шаг до 2, то придется сравнивать уже с 4, 5, 1, 8, 9, 10, 6, 2. Более наглядно видно на приложенном изображении.
Понятно, что проблем с получением ширины/высоты/диагонали нет, а вот в добавляющихся на каждом шагу точки(6/9 на втором, 7,11/13,14 на третьем) и состоит проблема.
Методы для сравнения есть, нужно создать алгоритм для получения позиций всех точек при заданном шаге. Делается всё на java [image: Изображение 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int height = ...          // высота изображения
int width = ...           // ширина изображения
int index0 = ...          // индекс точки, с которой сравниваете
int i0 = index0 / width;  // i-координата точки, с которой сравниваете
int j0 = index0 % width;  // j-координата точки, с которой сравниваете
int radius = ...          // шаг

for (int i = i0 - radius; i <= i0 + radius; ++i)
    for (int j = j0 - radius; j <= j0 + radius; ++j)
        if (0 <= i && i < height && 0 <= j && j < width) {
            int index = i * width + j;
            // тут сравнение
        }
```

Comment: Тот момент когда понял, что уже достаточно сидеть по ночам, ибо мозг атрофируется. Спасибо.